# three graphs that share an axis

Tags: r, graph, shared, axes

I need to make a graph that is composed of three graphs that share the same X axis but have separate Y axes. Is this possible to do in R, or do I need to make three independent graphs and put them together in a program like Adobe Illustrator?

[image: Three graphs that all have the same x axis that are stacked into one larger graph]

Comment: It's helpful when asking a plotting question to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data we can test with. It makes it harder to help you if we have to create test data to test a possible solution.

Comment: See ```ggplot2```'s documentation of ```facet_grid```

Comment: I agree with @MrFlick but the illustration is illustrative enough to easily deduce what OP is after.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(cyl ~ ., scales = "free_y") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using plot in the base package you can put multiple graphs in 1 window using the 
par command. Than just add your graphs in turning off the axis on the first 2. I would suggest reading the plot and graphics documentation to learn what you can tweak to get the plot looking good.

```
#############
# Data 
  x<-1:10
  y<- 1+ x*1.2
#############
par(mfrow=c(3,1)) # allow 3 graphs in the plot window 3 rows, 1 column
# plot 1
plot(x,y, axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA)   
box()
axis(2,seq(min(y), max(y),1), las=2)
# plot 2
plot(x,y, axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab="Y")  
box()
axis(2,seq(min(y), max(y),1), las=2)
# plot 3
plot(x,y, axes=T, xlab="X", ylab=NA)  
box()
axis(2,seq(min(y), max(y),1), las=2)
```